# syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm aware that this thread already exists.I already tried the previous solution but it still doesn't work. Help me out.

```
    public function default_theme_mod_values() {
        foreach ( Storefront_Customizer::get_storefront_default_setting_values() as $mod => $val ) {
            add_filter( 'theme_mod_' . $mod, function( $setting ) use ( $val ) { #Error log says that the syntax error is on this line
                return $setting ? $setting : $val;
            }, 10 );

        }
    }
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Are you still on PHP 5.2 or lower?

Comment: you realise your current code has commented the `{` ?

Comment: Is this a wordpress site? I find no reference to `add_filter` as a function unless you mean the wordpress hook

Comment: Ya this is a wordpress website. How do you check your php version?

Comment: There's a special function in PHP called [phpversion()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) that tells you the version of PHP; or yu can probably check through your control panel, or with your ISP

Comment: I'm running PHP 5.2 But Cpanel lets me change the PHP version. Which one should I be using and will affect other files?

Comment: [What has changed between 5.2 and 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.php); [What has changed between 5.3 and 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.php); [What has changed between 5.4 and 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.php); [What has changed between 5.5 and 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.php)

Comment: You should be using at least 5.5 these days, preferably 5.6.... the jump to PHP7 is probably a bit too much for you though

Comment: My PHP versions are only up to 5.4. Is there a way to download. Suppose I were to change my theme instead of trying to fix the code, would I regain control to edit my website.

Answer (score 0):

There is missing **{**

You need to use **{** after *( $val )*

Comment: It's there but commented out, OP may have commented out when describing their problem for this Question?

Comment: Ya, Martin is right. it's in my code already but it's not working